# "With that money that's a no-go" or "for that money that's a no-go"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if I need to use *with* or *for* in the context below?

> If you are paying only $500 for our service, then sorry, but **with**/**for** that money that's a no-go.

If neither preposition doesn't make that sound natural, how would you phrase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes more sense to use **for**, as you get something ("our service") **for** the money you pay, not **with**.

Perhaps I would say

> If you are only prepared to pay us $500 for our service, then that's [what you are expecting / asking for] a no-go.